# RDLC winforms report will not display data

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer, rdlc

Folks, I have a report that I created using the report wizard. I'm passing the Patient ID from Form1 to Form2 which hosts the report viewer. The report shows the headers and I am passing parameters into the query. However it displays no data at all. Here is the code behind. PatientID is certainly not null as I set a breakpoint.

```
        public BPReport(string PatientIDVal)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string PatientID = PatientIDVal.ToString();
        DateTime StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()).AddDays(-30);
        DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());

        txtPatientID.Text = PatientID.ToString();
        dtpStartDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate.ToShortDateString());
        dtpEndDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate.ToShortDateString());

        ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[3];
        param[0] = new ReportParameter("StartDate", StartDate.ToString());
        param[1] = new ReportParameter("EndDate", EndDate.ToString());
        param[2] = new ReportParameter("PatientID", PatientID.ToString());

        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

Comment: I take it that if you execute the query in the designer with the same parameters you get some data back?

Comment: That is correct which is why this is baffling me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this one was fixed by completely starting over on creating the report. I scrapped everything, did it again, and now it works. I suspect that is exactly what the resident experts here probably would have told me.